# how to split the data using string using java

Tags: java, string

`String str = sum(target_details.target_1_n)`

as target details 
 above String how to split the word using target

```
str.split("target")
```

but it can divided into `sum(target,_details.target_1_n)` as,details 
but i need on individal word split like `sum(target_details.target_1_n)` as ,details

Comment: Unless you provide some meaning to whatever it is you are trying to do, I don't think this question will ever make sense. What exactly are you trying to split?

Comment: I agree with Devilshnd, but if You try to split something or remove part of words, You can use regural expression.  Read about it

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure actually what you want to do but if you wish to separate the string by a token like "." or "_" you can do this:

```
String alfa = "something.stuff";
String[] result = alfa.split(".");
```

And it will return an array like this:

```
result[0] = "something"
result[1] = "stuff"
```